# PHP upload Image HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, https, upload

I have a form working fine to send images, to copy them and to resize them.

I switched the website in SSL with a GeoTrust certificate. Everything is working fine except the file upload.

The form is like this:

```
<form name='sendAvatar' method='post' action='if_avatar_resize.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' target="If_avatar_resize">
```

So I upload the file inside an iframe which has this code:

```
if (!copy($_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"], $dest_file)) {
  echo $_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"]."The copy of the file failed..\n".$dest_file ;
} else {
  echo $_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"]."Copy of the file OK " ;
}
```

With exactly the same file uploaded, when the site is in HTTPS, I have all the time the error message "The copy of the file failed"

So I checked the directory /tmp to see if the file is uploaded:

Without SSL:

```
-sh-3.2$ ll phpW7XSL6
-rw------- 1 apache apache 2279079 Jan 26 00:52 phpW7XSL6
-sh-3.2$ ll phpW7XSL6
ls: phpW7XSL6: No such file or directory
```

With SSL:

```
-sh-3.2$ ll phpbcUxyG
-rw------- 1 apache apache 2160218 Jan 26 00:53 phpbcUxyG
-sh-3.2$ ll phpbcUxyG
ls: phpbcUxyG: No such file or directory
```

So the upload of the file works fine whatever the form is in HTTPS or not and the file is uploaded in /tmp

On the other hand if the file is uploaded in HTTPS, the copy of the file does not work.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Use `is_uploaded_file` and `move_uploaded_file` functions instead of simple `copy`

Comment: Turn on error reporting and ad real error, not your own messages. You should also check for upload errors (`$_FILES['file_image']['error]`) before trying to move uploaded file.

Comment: Here is the new code, working on HTTP, still not working on HTTPS. `if(is_uploaded_file(realpath($_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"]))) {
  if (!move_uploaded_file(realpath($_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"]), $dest_file)) {
    echo $_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"]."The copy of the file has failed...\n".$dest_file ;
  } else {
    echo $_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"]."Copy of the file OK " ;
  }
} else {
  echo "File not uploaded!!!" ;
}`

I also checked `$_FILES['file_image']['error']` it returns 0 for HTTP and for HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Only little change in code

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"], $dest_file)) {
  echo $_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"]."Upload file failed..\n".$dest_file ;
} else {
  echo $_FILES['file_image']["tmp_name"]."Upload file Successfully..\n" ;
}
```

May this will help you ............. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same error message with `move_uploaded_file instead` of `copy` using HTTPS requests. The script works fine if I don't use HTTPS connection.
Maybe the issue comes from the Apache configuration.

Comment: Can you please check the Folder rights, generally it happens that folder donnot have access to upload the files.

Answer (score 0):

yes , we can't send $_FILES http site to https site. In other words, move_uploaded_files() function is use for move files only like http://abc.com to http://xyz.com not to https: site

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing a similar problem.

After testing my uploads on both purely HTTP and HTTPS: it seems that in SSL mode, exceeding PHP's `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` completely fails, and the $_FILES[...]["tmp_name"] is not populated.

Being that this was a freshly installed server the default was set @ 2M, which my upload tests exceeded.

I'm still looking for some documentation to back this, and a graceful way to still detect more robust errors.